# How do you add a "system" dependency in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a `pom.xml` that looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx-packager</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-packager</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0_40</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How do I do the same in Gradle?

**Update**: I tried doing this:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("${System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar")
}
```

as suggested by Giuseppe Ricupero, but I'm still getting the compile errors:

```
>gradle build

> Task :compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\custom-file-extension-windows-bundler\src\main\java\com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\CustomLauncherFileExtensionAppBundler.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import static com.oracle.tools.packager.StandardBundlerParam.*;
                                       ^
  symbol:   class StandardBundlerParam
  location: package com.oracle.tools.packager
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\custom-file-extension-windows-bundler\src\main\java\com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\CustomLauncherFileExtensionAppBundler.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import static com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WindowsBundlerParam.*;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class WindowsBundlerParam
  location: package com.oracle.tools.packager.windows
C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Dashman\code\custom-file-extension-windows-bundler\src\main\java\com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\CustomLauncherFileExtensionAppBundler.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
public class CustomLauncherFileExtensionAppBundler extends AbstractImageBundler {
```

The full `pom.xml` I'm trying to convert to Gradle is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.dynamicfiles.projects.javafx.bundler</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-file-extension-windows-bundler</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Danny Althoff</name>
            <email>fibrefox@dynamicfiles.de</email>
            <url>https://www.dynamicfiles.de</url>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <version.java.source>1.8</version.java.source>
        <version.java.target>1.8</version.java.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${version.java.source}</source>
                    <target>${version.java.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <display_version>${display_version}</display_version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx-packager</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-packager</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_40</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Update 2**: I tried `gradle init` like Giuseppe Ricupero recommended and it came up with this `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.javafx.bundler'
version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = """"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    system group: 'javafx-packager', name: 'javafx-packager', version: '1.8.0_40'
}
```

but that doesn't work, it throws this error:

```
> Could not find method system() for arguments [{group=javafx-packager, name=javafx-packager, version=1.8.0_40}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Comment: Add `println file("${System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar").absolutePath` to your build.gradle and ensure the path that is printed is correct, and that the JAR exists at that location.

Comment: @nickb: I did that an the path is definitely wrong: C:\Program Files\Java\lib\ant-javafx.jar

Comment: Looks like your question is answered, but that's why the original answer below didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The `gradle init` task automatically (try to?) convert(s) the `pom.xml` into the equivalent gradle files. You can try them:

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.javafx.bundler'
version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = ""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    system group: 'javafx-packager', name: 'javafx-packager', version:'1.8.0_40'
}
```

> settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'custom-file-extension-windows-bundler'
```

If you mix this with the original answer:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.javafx.bundler'
version = '1.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

description = """"""

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
}

dependencies {
    compile files("${System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')}/lib/ant-javafx.jar")
}
```

it works.

---

*Original answer*

I think you need just to add a file dep like:

```
dependencies {
    compile files("${System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')}/../lib/ant-javafx.jar")
}
```

You can see more in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies).

Comment: I tried this, not sure if it worked as I'm still seeing the compile errors.

Comment: @Pablo: this is a different deeper question but you can try to use the automatically converted files. I would have done something different manually because of the `system` dependency of maven but first it's better to try the vanilla.

Comment: @Pablo: thank you for directly updating the answer accordingly to your test. I noticed the path in files is slightly different in the solution: the relative upper directory `/../` is missing. Is it misswritten or are Gradle and Maven behave differently? (just out of curiousity)

Comment: They seem to behave differently. To be honest, once I got something working, I didn't dig too deep.